# Google sheets arrayformula of arrays

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to make an arrayformula in column B, which will copy whatever is in column A into C

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | `some (array)formula` | aaa *(the contents of A1)* |
| bbb |  | bbb *(the contents of A2)* |
| ccc |  | bbb *(the contents of A3)* |

at the moment I can use this formula on individual cells in column B: `={"",A1}`

However when I try to put this into an arrayformula: `=arrayformula({"",A1:A10})` it just returns an error:

> Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1.
> Actual: 9.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it.  Note that you need to have FALSE or 0 for the 4th split parameter (as illustrated) for this to work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT("|"&A1:A10,"|",0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=arrayformula(if(A1:A="",,A1:A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
=ArrayFormula({if(A:A="",,),A:A})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
=index(iferror(if({0/0,1},A:A)))
```

[image]

Or:

```
=query(A:A,"select 0/0, A label 0/0 ''")
```

[image]